# How to read an array of JSON objects in Node.js using require('./data.js')

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

The data stored is in data.js file (not JSON) and it is an array of objects. As an example,

```
 [
    {"id":"u4cse101", "name":"supriya","batch":"b"},
    {"id":"u4cse102", "name":"rahul", "batch":"a"},
    {"id":"u4cse345", "name":"ahalya", "batch":"a"}
 ]
```

I tried many methods, but couldn't achieve. Your help will be appreciated.
UPDATE:
One solution found is have the following in `data.js` file

```
JOURNAL = [
  {"x":"y"},
  {"a":"a"}
];
if (typeof module != "undefined" && module.exports)
  module.exports = JOURNAL;
```

and use the variable JOURNAL in another javascript file directly using `require('./data.js')`. But I am getting error:

```
if (typeof module != "undefined" && module.exports)
^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token if
```

Comment: `var fs = require('fs');
var array = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data.js', 'utf8'));`

Comment: Why not rename the file? JSON should be in `data.json`, not in `data.js` - the latter should be a JavaScript file, which JSON only technically is.

Comment: I neither want data.json file name or fs module. I have seen some code samples, they do it without these but I am not able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

you can save your json data file as `data.json` and use `require` to import json file

```
var jsn = require("./data.json");
jsn = JSON.parse(jsn);

//data.json
[
{"x":"y"},
{"a":"a"}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, you can follow this approach.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj;
fs.readFile('data.js', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  obj = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Hope it resolve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('data.js', 'utf8', function(error, data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
})
//or
var data = fs.readFileSync('data.js', 'utf8');
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The file should be

```
JOURNAL = [[
  {"x":"y"},
  {"a":"a"}
]];
```

instead of

```
JOURNAL = [
  {"x":"y"},
  {"a":"a"}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

data.json file

```
{
"firstname:"abc",
"lastname":"xyz"
}
```

And then your `route.js` file you can include `data.json` file and print the data value like that:

```
var fs = require('fs'), obj

// Read the file and send to the callback fucntion
fs.readFile('path of data.json file', fileHandler)

// Write the callback function

function fileHandler(err, data) {

    if (err) throw err
    obj = JSON.parse(data)
    // You can now play with your datas
}
```